# Remove cell border in HTML mail in Outlook 2013

Tags: email, outlook, html-table

I'm trying to remove three cell borders from a table in a HTML mail. My current situation is like this:

What I have
[image: What I have]

What I want
[image: What I want]

Code:

```
<html>

    <head>

        <style type="text/css">

            body
            {
                font-family:Calibri, Arial, Sans-Serif;
                font-weight:normal;
            }

            table
            {
                font-family:Calibri, Arial, Sans-Serif;
                font-weight:normal;
                font-size:14px;
                border-color:#CCCCCC;
                border-collapse:collapse;
                width:700px;
            }

            table th
            {         
                font-weight:bold;               
                padding:10px 5px;
                border-style:solid;
                border-width:1px;
                word-break:normal;
                border-color:#CCCCCC;
                background-color:#F0F0F0;
            }

            table td
            {
                padding:10px 5px;
                border-style:solid;
                border-width:1px;
                word-break:normal;
                border-color:#CCCCCC;
                background-color:#FFFFFF;
            }

            .td-left-column
            {
                font-style:italic;
                background-color:#F0F0F0;
                text-align:right;
                white-space:nowrap;
                width:100px;
            }

            p.italic
            {
                font-style:italic
            }

        </style>

    </head>

    <body>

        The script

        <br><br>

        <em>' + $ScriptName + '</em>

        has sent a notification. See below for details...

        <br><br>

        <table>

            <tr>
                <th colspan="2">Script</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="td-left-column">Path</td>
                <td>' + $ScriptPath + '</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="td-left-column">Server</td>
                <td>' + $Server + '</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="td-left-column">Name</td>
                <td>' + $ScriptName + '</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="td-left-column">Log-File</td>
                <td>' + $LogFileCell + '</td>
            </tr>

        </table>                

        <table>

            <tr>
                <th colspan="5">Backup Report</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="td-left-column" colspan="2">Path</td>
                <td colspan="3">' + $BckpDir + '</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="td-left-column" colspan="2">Save Type</td>
                <td colspan="3">' + $SaveType + '</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="td-left-column" colspan="2">Objects Saved</td>
                <td colspan="3">' + $FilesSaved + '/' + $TotalBckpFiles + '</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="td-left-column" colspan="2">Start</td>
                <td colspan="3">' + $Date + ' // ' + $Time + '</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="td-left-column" colspan="2">End</td>
                <td colspan="3">' + (Get-Date -Format d) + ' // ' + (Get-Date -Format t) + '</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="td-left-column" style="width:50px;"></td>
                <td class="td-left-column" style="width:50px;">Task</td>

                <td style="width:200px;text-align:center"><b>FTP Download</b></td>
                <td style="width:200px;text-align:center"><b>WinRAR Archive</b></td>
                <td style="width:200px;text-align:center"><b>Total</b></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="td-left-column" style="width:50px;"></td>
                <td class="td-left-column" style="width:50px;">RunTime</td>

                <td style="width:200px;text-align:center">' + $FTPDLRT + '</td>
                <td style="width:200px;text-align:center">' + $ArchiveRT + '</td>
                <td style="width:200px;text-align:center">' + $BckpRT + '</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="td-left-column" colspan="2">Size</td>
                <td colspan="3">' + [System.Math]::Round(($BckpSize / 1GB), 1) + ' GB</td>
            </tr>

            ' + $CompSize + '

            <tr>
                <td class="td-left-column" colspan="2">Free Disk Space</td>
                <td colspan="3">' + [System.Math]::Round(($BckpDsk.FreeSpace / 1TB), 1) + ' TB</td>
            </tr>

        </table>

        <br><br>

        <table>

            <tr>
                <th style="width:100px">ID</th>

                <th style="width:200px">File Name</th>

                <th style="width:200px">Size</th>

                <th style="width:200px">Status</th>
            </tr>

            ' + $AllFileRows + '

        </table>

    </body>

</html>
```

So far I've tried it by setting the border color to the background color of the cell but with no luck. Hiding the border with `border-bottom-style:hidden` did also not work.

Even more confusing is that when I add `border-left-color:#F0F0F0` into `<td class="td-left-column" style="width:50px;"></td>` the left border disappears. When I try to do this for the right border though, it doesn't work.

I've set up a fiddle right here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lk6bf5mm/3/
The problem is that if it looks good in the fiddle, it doesn't mean it will look the same in Outlook.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

One issue that may be causing your problem is that Outlook is stripping your  section out from your email. Make sure to add all CSS inline into the elements. Try setting the border to 0 and then use inline css to style the border on individual elements:

```
<table border="1">
```

Outlook 2013 uses Word to display HTML which has different rules. You can read more about what HTML and CSS is allowed here:

[Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

[Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338200(v=office.12).aspx)